# Convert element of a vector into type T C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, type-conversion

I have a templated function called `load` for a class where I load a text file and then inside the `load` function, I call another function that looks like this:

```
void add_edge    (std::string origin, std::string destination, T value);
```

In order to split the text file by line, I am using a pre-defined function that returns a `std::vector<std::string>` where each element can be accessed by doing this:

```
input: hello, world, 2
std::vector<std::string> words = my_func::split(line, ',');
std::cout << words[0]; // outputs hello
std::cout << words[1]; // outputs world
std::cout << words[2]; // outputs 2
```

I want to pass the three `words` elements into `add_edge` like this: `add_edge(words[0], words[1], words[2]);` but obviously this gives me compilation errors.

So I tried to just do a type cast of type T, like this:

```
T value = (T) words[2]; 
add_edge(words[0],words[1],value);
```

This still gave me compilation errors. I've been looking around online but nothing that I've seen really matches my situation. So how can I convert `words[2]` into a type T and then pass that into `add_edge`?

Edit: Here is the compilation error I'm getting.

```
error: invalid cast from type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'int'
```

The solution was to convert `words[2]` to an integer. Honestly I didn't realize it was that easy, I know almost nothing about templated types so I for sure thought I had to do something more tricky. Thank you for the help.

Comment: template <typename T> void add_edge    (std::string origin, std::string destination, T value); Could you show us what compilation errors?

Comment: What is `T` exactly? Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RonTang Here is the compilation error I'm getting: `error: invalid cast from type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'int'` And its of `template<class T>`

Comment: Why would this "obviously" gives you a compilation error?  ... something is setting `T` to `int`, and it is NOT the code you are showing.  Is `add_edge` a free function, or a method?

Comment: @Alex How would you store a string in an integer?

Comment: You can't use template as a cast. Template class are made to let you pass different type as parameter. So when you use '(T) words[2];' you should replace 'T' by a object or a fundamental types (eg : char *). As @RonTang said, provide the compilation errors can be helpfull here.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Using atoi or a istringstream.. which works. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex Use template when you have function with multiple signature. In your case, add_edge is `(string,string,int)` don't use template for that. But if you have a second function like this : `add_edge(string,string,float)`, you can think about using template. Just search for it and you will get a lot of nice tutorial.